# How can I call materialDesign components in C# using code and add to the wpf design?

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design, material-design-in-xaml

[My wpf design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zo09D.png)

What I want to do is
when I click on the chip I want it to add new chip to the StackPanel programmatically but the problem is how can I access or call the materialDesign components in the code and control theme?

Ex:

```
private void Chip_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        System.Windows.Controls.RadioButton rb= new System.Windows.Controls.RadioButton();       
        rb.Style = System.Windows.Application.Current.FindResource("MaterialDesignTabRadioButton") as Style;
        rb.Content = "hi";

        tabsRB.Children.Add(rb);
    }
```

here I add RadioButton to the StackPanel 
How can I add materialDesign Chip ?

Comment: I am not sure I am understanding what your actual problem is. Can't you just create a new `Chip` in the event handler the same way you are creating a `RadioButton`?

Comment: No I Can't becaus it is different in the wpf.

Comment: for radiobutton <RadioButton/>. but for chip <materialDesign:Chip/> I use materialDesign Nuget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing different between creating a `Chip` and creating a `RadioButton` in your code behind.  The only difference is the library that the classes are coming from and so you need to either have the proper `using` statements or you have to fully qualify the object (as you have done for your `RadioButton`).

```
private void Chip_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    var myChip = new MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.Chip()
    {
        Height = 50,
        Content = "My Chip Content",
        IsDeletable = true,
        ToolTip = "This is my Chip",
    };

    myChip.Click += ClickHandlerForMyChip;

    tabsRB.Children.Add(myChip);
}
```

Comment: I know a comment is not required when down voting, but it would help me improve the answer if I understood why it was down voted. Do you feel it needs more explanation?